# How to get the sum if the cell is checked

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get the sum of the cells that has a symbol on them with pre-assigned values.

[image]

tried all kinds of `sumifs()` and `ifs ()`.

Answer (score 2):

You may try `SUMPRODUCT()`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:D2)*(A3:D6<>""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this (Total Column sums up value of all the "check marks")?

My approach is to create 4 extra columns that looks up the corresponding value of the checkmark. If not found, the default value will be zero. Then, the total column will sum up the columns (E:H)

The formula to do the lookup is this: `=IFERROR(IF(MATCH("√",A3,0),$A$2,""),0)`

After that, you can hide columns E:H if you want.

[image: proposed solution]

Answer (score 0):

If your data don't have any text blanks.. then you can the below formula.

=SUMPRODUCT(--ISTEXT(A3:D3))

[image: Result]

if you feel that your data has text blanks, then you can use

=SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:D3="√"))